# Validate to check any special characteres with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, api, validation

I have a validate data and i have little trouble that i wanna know how to check if that any data must not include special characters such as: ~, @, #, $, %, &. If there are any special characters must report an error. Here is my validate request

```
// Validate request
if (!req.body.name) {
        res.status(400).send({
          message: "Name can not be empty!"
        });
        return;
      } else if (!req.body.color){
        res.status(400).send({
            message: "Color can not be empty!"
        });
        return;
      } else if (!req.body.brand) {
        res.status(400).send({
            message: "Brand can not be empty!"
        });
        return;
      }
```

How to check Name, Color, Brand must not include special characters. Please help or suggest me some ideas.

Comment: I want to take a suggestion for you. I think you should use a package to validate coming data like that. Because it will make your work easier than now

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RegExp.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to check if a string contains certain characters.

The code below will print true if `req.body.name` has anything other than alphanumeric characters.

```
const alphanumeric = /[^A-Za-z0-9]/;
console.log(alphanumeric.test(req.body.name));
```